# how to use MySql 5.7 as hive metastore as it need SSL parameter?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, ssl, hive, metastore

I am using MySQL 5.7 as Hive metastore . As ususal , my connection string is as follows

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

but i am getting following error 
.

```
Thu Nov 16 20:12:28 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.

.
So can anybody tell me how to pass SSl parameter in mysql connection string?? Or any other way i can solve  it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `useSSL=false` to connection string:

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
```